# Excessive fan speed when AC is plugged

Tags: laptop, fan

For some reason when I plug in the AC the laptop fun will always run, and it is quite noticable also. Is it supposed to be like that, is it some fix for it? My laptop is a thinkpad T400

Comment: I'll make this a comment since I'm not sure about the Thinkpad: My old HP laptop had an option in its BIOS, to always run the fan at full speed when the AC adapter is plugged in. Check your bios to see if you have a similar option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a quick search i found this website for thinkpad user with similiar problems

[Here](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_control_fan_speed)